# passport.js with express-validator in signup form and passport doesnt work

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, passport.js

I don't know how to use express validator with passport.js in sign up form and which of them save the user in database i send these files to check of it and inspect the error
also when i use passport alone without expressvalidator, it gives me always failureRedirect no succesRedirect

---

### the user routes file

```
    var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var User = require("../models/user");
var passport = require("passport");
/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});
router.get("/signup", function (req, res) {
    "use strict";
    res.render("signup", {title: "signup"});
});
router.get("/login", function (req, res) {
    "use strict";
    res.render("login", {title: "login"});
});
router.get("/profile", function (req, res, next) {
    "use strict";
    res.render("user/profile");
});
router.post("/signup", function (req, res, next) {
    "use strict";
    // form values
    var name = req.body.name;
    var username = req.body.username;
    var email = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;
    var confirmpassword = req.body.confirmpassword;
    //check for profile image
    if (req.files && req.files.profileimage) {
        var profileImageOriginalNmae = req.files.profileimage.originalname;
        var profileImageName = req.files.profileimage.name;
        var profileImagePath = req.files.profileimage.path;
        var profileImageExt = req.files.profileimage.extention;
        var profileImageSize = req.files.profileimage.size;
        var profileImageMimeType = req.files.profileimage.mimetype;
    } else {
        var profileImageNmae = "noimage.png";
    }
    //check form validation
    req.checkBody("name", "name is required").notEmpty();
    req.checkBody("username", "username is required").notEmpty();
    req.checkBody("email", "email is invalid").isEmail();
    req.checkBody("password", "password is required").notEmpty();
    req.checkBody("confirmpassword", "password does not match").equals(req.body.password);
    //check for errors
    var errors = req.validationErrors();
    if (errors) {
        res.render("signup", {
            errors: errors,
            name: name,
            username: username,
            email: email,
            password: password,
            confirmpassword: confirmpassword
        });
    } else {
        var newUser = new User({
            name: name,
            username: username,
            email: email,
            password: password,
            profileimage: profileImageName
        });
        User.createUser(newUser, function (err, user) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            console.log(user);
        });
         //success message
            req.flash("success_msg", "now you can login");
            
            res.redirect("/user/login");
    }
}, passport.authenticate("local-signup", {
    successRedirect: "/user/profile",
    failureRedirect: "/user/login",
    failureFlash: true

}));
module.exports = router;
```

### this is my passport file

```
    // importing passport modules
    var passport = require("passport");
    var LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
    var User = require("../models/user");
    passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
        "use strict";
        done(null, user.id);
    });
    passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
        "use strict";
        User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
            done(err, user);
        });
    });
    passport.use("local-signup", new LocalStrategy({
        usrnameField: "username",
        passwordField: "password",
        passReqToCallback: true
    }, function (req, username, password, done) {
        "use strict";
        User.findOne({"username": username}, function (err, user) {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }
            if (user) {
                return done(null, false, {message: "username is already un use"});
            } else {
                var newUser = new User();
                newUser.username = username;
                newUser.password = password;
            }
        });
    }));
## this is user routes file ##
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var User = require("../models/user");
var passport = require("passport");
/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});
router.get("/signup", function (req, res) {
    "use strict";
    res.render("signup", {title: "signup"});
});
router.get("/login", function (req, res) {
    "use strict";
    res.render("login", {title: "login"});
});
router.get("/profile", function (req, res, next) {
    "use strict";
    res.render("user/profile");
});
router.post("/signup", function (req, res, next) {
    "use strict";
    // form values
    var name = req.body.name;
    var username = req.body.username;
    var email = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;
    var confirmpassword = req.body.confirmpassword;
    //check for profile image
    if (req.files && req.files.profileimage) {
        var profileImageOriginalNmae = req.files.profileimage.originalname;
        var profileImageName = req.files.profileimage.name;
        var profileImagePath = req.files.profileimage.path;
        var profileImageExt = req.files.profileimage.extention;
        var profileImageSize = req.files.profileimage.size;
        var profileImageMimeType = req.files.profileimage.mimetype;
    } else {
        var profileImageNmae = "noimage.png";
    }
    //check form validation
    req.checkBody("name", "name is required").notEmpty();
    req.checkBody("username", "username is required").notEmpty();
    req.checkBody("email", "email is invalid").isEmail();
    req.checkBody("password", "password is required").notEmpty();
    req.checkBody("confirmpassword", "password does not match").equals(req.body.password);
    //check for errors
    var errors = req.validationErrors();
    if (errors) {
        res.render("signup", {
            errors: errors,
            name: name,
            username: username,
            email: email,
            password: password,
            confirmpassword: confirmpassword
        });
    } else {
        var newUser = new User({
            name: name,
            username: username,
            email: email,
            password: password,
            profileimage: profileImageName
        });
        User.createUser(newUser, function (err, user) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            console.log(user);
        });
         //success message
            req.flash("success_msg", "now you can login");
            
            res.redirect("/user/login");
    }
}, passport.authenticate("local-signup", {
    successRedirect: "/user/profile",
    failureRedirect: "/user/login",
    failureFlash: true

}));
module.exports = router;
```

`